# Fold/curl edge of UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview

I need to fold/unfold the edge of UIImageView to mark as a favorite. I searched across multiple sites, but have not found anything about it.

I attached some example images, and, if possible, with animation effect.

[image: Fold]
[image: Fold 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to animate the view usign OpenGL. There is a nice library for that called [XBPageCurl](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fxissburg%2FXBPageCurl&ei=9t1ZUOW2IKLK0AXH4YCABw&usg=AFQjCNH8OtMTlWp-Pg4eXy9l9wNu0oGBkw)

However, you could achieve a much lighter solution by creating a mask for the curl effect and animate your view while transitioning to it. Here is what it would look like

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

UIImage *maskedImage = [yourImage imageMaskedWithImage:yourMask];
[yourImageView setImage:maskedImage];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

To know how to mask an image, have a look here http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Answer (score 0):

can be done with `UIViewController`'s `presentModalViewController:animated:` and setting the `modalTransistionStyle` to `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`. See [apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Kai, thanks, but fold effect should be tiny on any edge of UIImageView,  so I can not use the default animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func curl(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    
    if b == 1 {
    UIView.transition(with: imageview, duration: 1.5, options: .transitionCurlUp, animations: {self.imageview.isHidden = true}, completion: nil)
        b = 2
    }
    else if b == 2
    {
        self.imageview.isHidden  = false
        UIView.transition(with: imageview, duration: 1.5, options: .transitionCurlDown, animations: {self.imageview.isHighlighted = true}, completion: nil)
        b = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).